# Calling onDestroy for Activity after clicking on deep link notification in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a problem in Jetpack Compose: the activity keeps calling onStart -> onStop -> onDestroy methods after I clicked on the deepLink navigation notification, even though I reached the ChatScreen target

My gradle:
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7"

Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".presentation.ui.main_screens_activity.ui.MainScreensActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screens"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Chatalyze"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="scheme_chatalyze" />
                <data android:host="call_screen" />
                <data android:scheme="app" />
                <data android:host="calls_screen" />
                <data android:host="chat_screen" />

            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<!--                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->

                <data android:scheme="scheme_chatalyze2" />
                <data android:host="chat_screen2" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
```

Notification class

```
 private fun getPendingIntent(
        name: String?,
        sender: String,
        recipient: String,
        context: Context,
   
    ): PendingIntent {
            val deepLink =
                Uri.parse("scheme_chatalyze2://chat_screen2/{$name}/{$sender}/{$recipient}")

            val intent = Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                deepLink
            )

            return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context.applicationContext, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
    }
```

NavigationGraph

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
@Composable
fun MainScreensNavigationGraph(navHostController: NavHostController) {

    Log.d("4444", " ChatalyzeNavigationGraph loaded")
    NavHost(navController = navHostController, startDestination = ScreenRoute.ChatsScreen.route) {
        composable(route = ScreenRoute.ChatsScreen.route) {
            ChatsScreen(navController = navHostController)
        }
        composable(
            route = ScreenRoute.ChatScreen.route,
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink {
//                    uriPattern = "scheme_chatalyze2://chat_screen2/{$RECIPIENT_NAME}/{$RECIPIENT_PHONE}/{$SENDER_PHONE}"
                    uriPattern =
                        "scheme_chatalyze2://chat_screen2/{$RECIPIENT_NAME}/{$RECIPIENT_PHONE}/{$SENDER_PHONE}"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                }
            ),
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(RECIPIENT_NAME) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(RECIPIENT_PHONE) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(SENDER_PHONE) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )
        ) { entry ->
            val recipientName = entry.arguments?.getString(RECIPIENT_NAME)
            val recipientPhone = entry.arguments?.getString(RECIPIENT_PHONE)
            val senderPhone = entry.arguments?.getString(SENDER_PHONE)
            IfLetHelper.execute(recipientName, recipientPhone, senderPhone) {
                ChatScreen(
                    navHostController = navHostController,
                    recipientName = it[0],
                    recipientPhone = it[1],
                    senderPhone = it[2]
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Target Screen

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun ChatScreen(
    viewModel: ChatScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    recipientName: String,
    recipientPhone: String,
    senderPhone: String,
) {
    Log.d("4444", " ChatScreen loaded")
}
```

I also tried doing fun getPendingIntent() differently, but it still ends up onDestroy for the MainScreenActivity screen, although I achieved the ChatScreen goal

```
 private fun getPendingIntent(
        name: String?,
        sender: String,
        recipient: String,
        context: Context
    ): PendingIntent {

           val deepLink = Uri.parse("scheme_chatalyze2://chat_screen2/{$name}/{$sender}/{$recipient}")
      val deepLinkIntent = Intent(
          Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
          deepLink,
//          context,
//          MainScreensActivity::class.java
      )

      val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
          addNextIntentWithParentStack(deepLinkIntent)
          getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
      }
      return resultPendingIntent
```

At the very least, have the activity recreated but only stop at onStart.
I've tried using all launch mode types, but the behavior is the same.

I also tried using onNewIntent() in MainScreenActivity and calling deepLink inside, but it still ends up with onDestroy for the MainScreenActivity screen, although I achieved the ChatScreen goal